# Converting User Profile Sync into partition mode

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, multi-tenancy

We're in the process of rearchitecting our farm to make it more of a multi-tenant environment, and I was wondering... is it possible to partition an existing user profile application, or do I have to recreate it from scratch? (We have about 600 users, so I don't want to mess up their My Sites or any other configuration.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's not possible. You can only specify a service application to be partitioned upon creation.

That said, I've not seen any successful multi-tenant SharePoint environments other than the Office365 one. It involves a lot of plumbing and custom development to arrive at a state that enables solid operations. Furthermore, the stringent AD requirements make it less suitable to implement when you already have a lot of users in your directory.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yeah, our main goal is to be able to split My Sites into two different buckets.

Now, if I were to create new UPS, can I migrate users, or at a minimum point their My Sites over the new one? I'd figure so, right -- at least from PowerShell...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to accomplish?

Comment: Sure thing. What I am mainly after is the ability to separate users of one SharePoint instance from the others. Mainly for the sake of having dedicated My Sites URLs as well as dedicated people-picker searches. Thanks!

Comment: So... I was able to migrate UPS to a multitenant environment, with all their properties and everything... but OneDrive is not giving me fits, with a "Could not load user profile" error. Thoughts? (Question posted here now: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111654/could-not-load-user-profile-on-onedrive-after-migration-to-multitenancy)